# Why do I need iCloud Music if I sync to Touch

Tags: itunes, icloud, ipod-touch, apple-music, music.app

I have a large music library in iTunes on PC, which contains music I have purchased from Apple and music I added to my library from physical CDs.

I have an iPod Touch and access to Apple Music. When I try to add something to a playlist or my library on the Touch, I am asked to use iCloud Music Library.

I eventually relented and am uploading my music library to iCloud Music Library to get the added features.

My question is -- why do I need to use iCloud Music Library when all my music is physically synced to the iPod Touch anyway? The Touch doesn't need to access the music in iCloud, as it is already synced.

After activating iCloud Music Library on iTunes and the Touch I can now add albums to a playlist via the Touch, which then appear as a playlist in iTunes, which is pretty nice :)

Comment: Did you mean iCloud Music Library?

Comment: @iTunes: Yes; I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  You state you decided to use iCloud Music Library "to get the added features" but then you ask why you need it.  The only reason to use iCloud Music Library is to get access to your songs on all your devices.  So why did you get it?

Comment: 1. I already have access to all my songs on my Touch because I synced it via the USB cable. I used iCloud Music Library because I "had to" to get added features like adding albums/sons to playlists or library. I'm wondering why I need to upload 100Gb of music into the Cloud to get these features when that 100Gb is music is already on the Touch.

Comment: 2. The Touch already contains 100Gb of music on it. I'd like to add albums/songs to playlists/library on the Touch. To get this to work, I have to use iCloud Music Library and to do *that* I have to upload 100Gb of music into the Cloud. Music that's already on the Touch.